# How can I convince employees to solve their own IT problems?

Tags: communication, productivity

My job scope includes providing desktop support to office staff, but that is not the only purpose I am hired for. I am primarily a programmer.

I have been practicing IT for years and my philosophy in this IT-driven era is that everyone should continuously get hands-on with IT. For example, learning a programming language can dramatically increase your own productivity. A computer to a Sales Manager is equivalent to a machine to an operator. If you can't handle your tools, then you deserve to fail.

However, to this date there are still people who don't know what a taskbar is, how to create shortcuts and understand why they should keep files in My Documents and not to save files in C: root.

Despite their obvious lack of skill, they continue to take for granted the IT support  to the extent of blaming us for taking too long to reset their forgotten passwords as if we have a lot of time.

I believe in the long run educating these people would cut business costs by reducing desktop support staff and reduce downtimes overall. Unfortunately, it seems that most people still hold the perception of "this is your job, so just fix it while I go make a cup of coffee".

If you are IT support, what do you do? If you are not, how can I convince you to LEARN to solve your problems? I'll teach.

**EDIT**:
I realised that people are treating my post like a rant because, I admit, it does sound like one. So, I would like to clarify:

I am not an expert, know-it-all or good teacher. Thus, I am especially puzzled by people who are uninterested to avoid/solve their own IT problems. They rather wait for someone to fix it than to explore or try out on their own first. I must say that I have no problems fixing their problems at all because it is my job afterall. What I am unhappy about is the indifferent attitude as if they have no fault or obligation. I feel that both for the company and their own good, they can be made to understand that there is a cost involved if they don't handle their tools well. But how? That is the question.

So there are suggestions on how to support their learning, but we haven't got any that can motivate them to be interested to learn in the first place. I think, I will have to accept answers that says "it's not possible" soon.

Comment: if it is indeed _taking too long to reset their forgotten passwords_ then you can hardly expect them to trust you enough to teach them IT. Your note about "as if we have a lot of time" makes me sense a managerial problem there: understaffed IT support - if this is so, your chances to improve things are quite low

Comment: Whether it is too long is subjective, depends on several factors including expectations and personal patience levels. But bottom line is that I don't feel we should get more staff to reset people's password, if we can educate them to simply write them down. I thought long and hard, and don't find it an unreasonable request for them to learn. It's for cutting costs and for their own benefit afterall.

Comment: For example, if their outlook doesn't connect for the first time, I am happy to go and check and then inform them that their password has expired, and please go to [website] to reset. But you can't tell me after 2 years in the company you still need me to remind you? You certainly should not need more IT staff to become nannies.

Comment: writing down passwords - as a means to cut IT efforts? Hm hmmmmmmmmmm. With all due respect I for one wouldn't want to _learn_ from IT guy suggesting stuff like that

Comment: @gnat I saw that coming. But remember these are non-professionals. You have to take it step by step.

Comment: "Non professionals" or "Non-IT professionals"?  When we overhauled out IT security, our ITSM gave several different approaches for staff that allowed them to memorise secure passwords easily.

Comment: @Jake - Sounds like you should do your job and not complain. I would create word documents that explain "step by step" how do something. If they still need help after that I would go help them. I also agree this seems like a rant.  Sounds like your problem is how your teaching people to do something.  As for not remembering how to reset our passwords, we have more important things to remember, then something we use once every 90 days.

Comment: @guym can you share what are the methods used?

Comment: @Ramhound "we have more important things to remember" is the kind of attitude that is pervasive. I think it's rather arrogant and at the same time demeaning to others who do remember passwords. Let's not just argue about password and go off topic. My question is asking how to make people learn. I take it as you are saying it's not possible.

Comment: @Jake - I remember my passwords.  What I don't remember is how to change them every 90 days.  I am saying the problem is clearly your attitude and how your teaching people.  I am saying provide the information so people can look it up.  I won't even mention what I do because you would be shocked.

Comment: I think that you post is a bit of a rant and that you need to be more flexible in your expectations of what people should and should not know. The fact that you're expected to be a programmer AND desktop support is a problem with you and your boss. It has nothing to do with the users who need desktop support.

Comment: BTW, I NEVER store anything under "My Documents" or any other path with a space in it. :-)

Comment: @Ramhound Regardless of what you do, if the security policy is for you to change password, their is no good reason for you to forget how to change and as a result delay your work. There are people like you who will at least remember where to look it up so the problem is mitigated, that's fair. Still there are some who repeatedly ask for help.

Comment: When a user is required to do something not related to their daily work (such as change a password), the automated prompt that tells them to do the thing should also include instructions on how to do it. If you do something every 90 days, you're unlikely to remember how to do it... Part of IT's job is making it easy for employees to follow company policy.

Comment: *how can I convince you to LEARN to solve your problems?* - That is a rather rude way to ask people whom you are asking to take time to help you help yourself... how can we get you to just Shut up and fix our problems while we get coffee?

Comment: There is a good question in here but you have not even made any real  attempt to ask it... voting to close until it if fixed.

Answer (score 15):

Your question is sounding a bit like a rant, but I see a few scenarios here.

### Why do we need IT support, can't people just learn?

Short answer is "no, they can't". Or rather, they won't. People are hired to do specific tasks. Some work with sales, some in marketing and so forth. While it's true that computers are an intrinsic tool in many of these professions, it's also true that computers are still, despite our best efforts, hard to use and easy to mess up. Hence the need for IT support.

Sure, you could do away with that support, if all employees were trained up to some equivalency of super-user level. That, however, is a strategic decision for the company as a whole, not for the individual. It requires time and effort to train, time taken away from the core tasks of each employee so it has to be equated with an investment for the company. So if you want to change your companies approach to IT support, you need to sell your top management on this - not individual employees. And be prepared for a cost/benefit discussion weighing training cost against the cost of maintaining IT support.

### I'm hired to do support, but I don't like it

This is something you need to discuss with your immediate supervisor or manager as it cuts to the core of your job description and what you were hired for. Perhaps you thought that your job would involve more programming and less support or perhaps you just don't like to work with support. Either way, if there is a discrepancy between what **you** think your job should be and what **your employer** think your job should be, you need to work to resolve that. But trying to get your coworkers to adapt or change just to accommodate your ideal work-day is plain unreasonable - they have their own jobs to do just as you have yours.

### The support-load is too high and I don't have enough time to fulfill my duties

This one is easy - if your load is too high and you feel that you don't have time to complete all your duties, start a discussion with your superiors about hiring additional support personnel. Document your work-load, how long it takes to act on support tickets etc. to get some supporting metrics.

### People should appreciate the work of IT support

> Despite their obvious lack of skill, they continue to take for granted the IT support...

This is a pain I can absolutely sympathize with. Support functions in general (and IT support definitely) often go under-appreciated. This is often tied to the particular culture at a company. Strictly hierarchical organizations tend to measure an employee's value based on where they are in the hierarchy, rather than what they contribute to the whole. Since support functions is often not high up on the totem-pole, they get under-valued.

However, most of the time it's not **you** people take for granted, it's the **service you provide**. Much in the same way as you take for granted that the sales-organization is going to sell and that the manufacturing division is going to, well, manufacture they all expect support to do that - support. And why not? It's your job after all. But it's not personal, that's the key.

It's also the way forward. Once you stop taking it personal and start looking at what you do as a service, you can start to make rational determinations and suggest strategies to improve it.

- A lot of your time is consumed by repeating, mundane requests - perhaps you could create some form of self-help process or tools for the most common support issues
- Response time is too long and people get upset - maybe you need to hire more support personnel
- People require more support than reasonable - perhaps your IT and desktop infrastructure is overly complicated. Or maybe all employees should get more/better IT training.
- etc.

But remember, these are all investments and the best way for you to contribute is to help the company make a positive cost/benefit determination (assuming it is).

Comment: I admit that this question was inspired by a rant. But my main objective is to check if there are companies out there who embrace this idea of making staff learn the importance of solving problems themselves, and if so, how do they do it. Of course we still need support staff to fix complicated problems, but there are some tasks I feel can be taught and reduce downtime waiting for support to come around. But I get your point, people don't see it as their benefit to learn.

Comment: @Jake "if there are companies out there who embrace this idea of making staff learn the importance of solving problems themselves" -- well such could be only companies who could _afford to hire problem-solvers_ as their staff to start with, and that wouldn't likely be cheap. I guess even if there are such companies, these would be rather exception/elite than a rule/typical. Cost of "entry ticket" is pretty high so to speak

Comment: Many companies DO embrace problem solvers. Its just the problems they solve aren't necessarily directly related to IT and their desktops. One of the bitter truths of IT desktop support is that they are still considered the equivalent of the "A/V" crew from high school.

Answer (score 5):

Support roles can be irritating, at times - we had a client claim our software "didn't work" because he was getting an error message.  The error was "Your disc is full.." when writing out a file.  Sigh.

Unfortunately, from what you have described, it is part of your role to offer this kind of support to people who are not as technically gifted or competent as yourself.

I suspect that even of you offer to train senior staff at their desks, they will feel awkward about revealing their lack of knowledge; it can be veery difficult when faced with basic questions not to sound patronising when you respond, and this creates a further barrier to training.  Training, by and large, is all about patience.

In the mean time, I would suggest that you look at what you can do proactively to create support material for common issues.  For example :

***- set up a Wiki/Intranet for staff, with active and helpful IT tips and tricks***

***- use screen capture software to extend this with the use of videos***

***- create a guide for new staff to help them understand the IT, and where to find help***

***- get the IT manager to order in a stock of the "for dummies" books***

***- set up lunchtime "familiarisation" seminars where you can train multiple people***

This takes time to do, but its well worth the investment as you build up a body of knowledge.  To some extent, StackExchange provides the same set up.

These are all the approaches we have used to lower out software support burden, and over time they have been highly effective for us.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments you seem to be finding that people "don't want to learn";  generally this applies when they are not engaged with the teaching/coaching style you have adopted.

For example, **showing** people what to do is a lot less effective than **telling** them what to do, and having them do it while you offer support.

Training, coaching and teaching are all skills that need to be learned and refined.  If this is part of your role, you might want to look at "train the trainer" courses that could help you to be more effective.

Comment: I started the IT guide for new comers a few months after I joined, naively thinking that it would answer most of the questions I will get from new comers. The way I conduct it is I sit with the new comer and walk through every single procedure and software, from where the switch is to how to shutdown before going home, writing everything down for them to keep. I was naive. They didn't take it seriously at all. 10 out of 10 times, they throw my notes away, and have to ask me the same questions the next day.

Comment: You have pointed out the ways we can teach them, but I feel really what we need is a way to make them understand the need to learn. That's the part I am stumped.

Comment: @Jake - I've not pointed out ways to teach them.  I've pointed out ways in which you can support their self-learning.  These have been used by my team, and our internal IT team, to great effect.  The issue is not that they don't want to learn, just that the teaching methods and/or style you are using are not being effective.  Effective teaching and training is a difficult skill to learn and master, as is effective coaching.  How much training have you had in these fields?

Comment: "How much training have you had in these fields" is precisely why I had to resort to asking this question. Seems like so people are quite negative towards my question so far. Even if you have methods to support their learning, how do you play a part to make them want participate in learning? It's not like they are looking for a knowledgebase but can't find one, is that they don't see the importance of learning.

Comment: @jake, of course they aren't interested in learning this stuff anymore than I'm interested in learning how my car engine works. There is no reason why they would be interested. Are you interested in learning accounting?

Comment: @Jake - The negativity is, I suspect, because people see your question as saying "How can I change everyone else to make my job easier?" The answer is - you can't.  All you can do is change yourself, the way you engage with people, and what you do.  Check out "Seven Habits of Highly Sucessful People" by Stephen Covey.  Two of the habits are "Seek first to understand, then be understood" and "Be Proactive."  Your comments seem to suggest you are reacting to a situation and not trying to understand others first.

Comment: @Jake Have you tried asking them how they prefer to learn?

Comment: @HLGEM I am interested in learning accounting and your car engine. Honest. Curiosity and learning makes us a better person.

Comment: @GuyM when asked whether they are interested, most attitude is of "I have better things to do", "it's not my job". Only a handful are interested to ask "so what happened?", "how can I avoid it next time".

Comment: @GuyM I think your comment about the negativity is right. And by asking this question, I am really trying to change my approach that's why I asked "how". Sadly, people seems to only read the part where it says I am going to convince them. My question clearly asked: "if you are not IT support, HOW can I convince you to learn?" which is perhaps a bad phrasing of "HOW do you prefer to learn?". But really, my intention is the same.

Comment: @Jake You cannot "convince" people that they "need to learn."  You need to motivate them to learn, and ideally, to learn for theselves.  To do that, you need to understand the different ways in which people learn, which learning style(s) suit the person, and how to teach to those styles efficiently.  My suggestions have covered five different learning approaches (online, books, videos, talks, guides, tell/show) all of which different people respond to.   How many of these do you currently use?  Which ones work well, and which do not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6814/discussion-between-guym-and-jake)

Comment: @Jake, I think your response to HLGEM was rude (at best). You understood the point he was making. If you are really interested in learning about accounting and car engines then why haven't you already? Oh, you have too many other things to do and learn that are more important. Same goes for all those people who you feel don't want to learn about IT. I'll bet most of them would love to be IT experts, however, they have other things to do and learn that are more important to them. That's why you get paid for IT Support and they don't.

Comment: @Dunk I think you are making too many assumptions about me. I am not an expert in accounting nor car engines. But coincidentally, I have done both before. HLGEM said "There is no reason why they would be interested". And I agree. My question was, how do I convince (which could be a bad choice of word) them to learn, to be interested to solve IT problems. Did you get my point? I invite you to join the chat GuyM created.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need to develop some strategies to cope with users complaining to you regarding their password resets (or similar) as well as teaching them to teach themselves. The only alternative is to stop supporting the users and convince your business to take on a support person whose sole role is to reset people's passwords, show them how turn on their PC, etc.

I am going to assume you business cannot afford, or is not willing to hire a dedicated support person. So, what can you do with your current situation which will help to make your life easier, and let you get on with programming?

**Password Resets**

You mention in your post that users complain when their password doesn't get reset in a timely manor. Can you automate this process either through the program itself, or through some sort of script you write?

**Get FAQ'd**

Get some simple one-page FAQs together. I know you said you had a whole course for newbies, but you need to cater to the lowest common denominator. If someone requests something common, you reply with the FAQ. Again, you could almost automate this.

**Change the Support Process**

In a previous job I would receive support issues of random usefulness via email. Sometimes it was a whole report (Good), sometimes it was a one lines saying something somewhere may or may not be working right. I changed the support process. After a grace period, anyone who made a support request had to submit one via an email template. Not using the template resulted in a standard reply of "Please use the template". 
In your situation, this may help you to receive better information on their issues so you can send them the correct FAQ.

**Get Business Support**

Look at your job spec. Are you spending more, or less, time on support than was specified. If it is too much, speak to your bosses with ideas such as the ones I have outlined above. Propose these to them, such that you will be able to serve them better in your other role.

**Get a Buddy**

My final suggestion is find someone to buddy up with. For example, if you requests are always coming from one department, find the person who makes the fewest requests and get him on board with supporting you. That way, they will go to him/her first before coming to you.

Comment: good, practical and reasonable guidance overall, I have only one caveat regarding _email template_ submission. Using this approach, IT would better provide a failover option to report the cases when, well, the very issue is that email is broken. Web form, or messenger, or something else...

Comment: @SheyMouse "So, what can you do with your current situation which will help to make your life easier, and let you get on with programming?" -- You give good suggestions, but I am dissapointed that the community so far has misunderstood my intention and have turned rather aggressive. Maybe is my bad choice of words, but I cannot explain any better. I am not looking for an easy way out at all, in fact I am looking to do more to get people educated because I feel it benefits everyone as a whole. Really, nobody think that learning to be independant is good for themselves?

Comment: @Jake - My comment did attempt to take your wish to get people educated into account. The first step is getting the people you deal with to learn is to teach them where to look for the knowledge. People won't think if they don't have to. Replying with a FAQ they have to read to solve their issue is a start. Remember, the FAQ can have anything in it, including "If you have similar issues in the future why not go here: " and add a link to a wiki, webpage, whatever.